# SharePoint as a Client Portal

Tags: document-library, features

For the record, I am not familiar with SharePoint.

My company is looking to create a file portal for clients to access our documentation. This is strictly a need for the clients; there is no need for internal sharing. We need to have a folder structure and be able to assign permissions.

1) Is SharePoint a good option for us?

2) Are these features available on SharePoint out-of-the-box?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes.

Comment: Yes, This feature is available in the SharePoint.
You have the option of Document Library.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/document-library-creation-in-sharepoint-2013-online/

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online would be your obvious choice where you can share with unlimited number of external users at no extra cost. The external user would gain access through e-mail invitation (by you) to their company e-mail. The external user would sign in using a Microsoft Account (Live-ID or Office 365 account), but have notifications sent to their company e-mail.

Starting now, you could have this up and running before lunch.